# How to move among the items of a Combobox without selecting them like highlighting?

Tags: c#, arduino

I am working on my software design project and I need to use serial communication between arduino and computer. I use 3 buttons in the project, 2 buttons are for moving the highlighted item in Combobox and the other one is to select the item. I tried to do it that way but somehow it can only select when I press the buttons to move them. Is it possible to do that it changes the highlight of the items?

Comment: Is it possible for you to post a screenshot of what you need?

Comment: @Idle_Mind Here is the GIF of what I want to do with those buttons(Up / Down). https://media.giphy.com/media/WrhBB3p8lfSqcesfBf/giphy.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you making the "move" buttons change the selected item?

Anyway, to select an item in the ComboBox, use the [SelectedIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex?view=netframework-4.8) property:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1; // selected the second item
}
```

Not sure how you're receiving commands from your Arduino, but when you want to send an up arrow, you could call:

```
private void ArrowUp()
{
    SendKeys.Send("{Up}");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest but the things is I want to highlight the item of the combobox before I select them. For example you drag  your mouse on the item you want to choose and the item gets highlighted before you select it. I am using 3 different buttons on Arduino. Up button, Select button and the Down button. If I press the select button when the dropdown property is false, it drops down and then if I want to select an item I go to my item using those buttons and press the Select button. It never works because I automatically selects the item when I use Up/Down buttons.

Comment: Okay.  You can make the drop down portion visible by setting `DroppedDown = true`.  Edited code above.

Comment: Is it possible If I press the button on Arduino and bind it as arrow keys, so that it will move as the button is pressed ?

Comment: See [SendKeys.Send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: I really appreciate for your help. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is when button is read I wrote this code, SendKeys.Send("{UP}"); or SendKeys.Send("{DOWN}"); depending on the button.